# Why does proxy_pass cause try_files to fail?

Tags: nginx, server, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

my config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    error_log /dev/stdout debug;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header Host www.google.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-PORT $remote_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ^~ /subapp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # return 200 hint;
    }
}
```

I use curl to test:

```bash
curl http://localhost/subapp/test
```

If I use `return 200`, I got "hint".

But when I use `try_files`, I get the `proxy_pass` result?

If I remove the `proxy_pass`, I get the correct result.

Comment: The URI `/index.html` is processed by the `location /` block. Do you mean `/subapp/index.html`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yeah. Requesting `/subapp/*` always gets the content of google.com

Comment: @RichardSmith But I want it to return the contents of /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html.

Comment: You could use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` to access the HTML file from the root. But where are the CSS and JS files?

Comment: @RichardSmith The css files and js files are located in `/usr/share/nginx/html`, and I want to map it to `/subapp/*`. As an example, map `/subapp/main.js` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/main.js`

Comment: I solved my problem with the following configuration, but I don't know why =404 works.

```nginx
    location ^~ /subapp {
        rewrite ^/subapp(/.*)$ $1 break;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
```